# How to prevent Javascript print from blocking other scripts

Tags: javascript, printing, firefox-addon, dom-events

I am writing a Firefox application, where I substitute content of a `<browser>` element for printing, i.e. when you click browser the following is done:

1. printable version is generated
2. browser navigates to this printable version
3. browser content is printed
4. browser navigates back to original page

The problem is that the original page has some important Javascript handling while it is loaded, but printing operation (and it may take quite a while) blocks Javascript.

As a result, what happens is that when page is loaded printing is in process, so page's Javascript is blocked => page is not complete.

Is there any way to prevent print method from blocking Javascript?
Or any way to catch event `printComplet`e or something - so that I could trigger navigation when Javascript is no longer blocked?
Maybe there are some other workarounds...?

Comment: It's bad by design to "print for me." I recommend you let the user print a printer friendly view of your app.

Comment: You should be using a print stylesheet to create your printable version rather than javascript. Look at [@media types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@media).